# Is it reasonable to define repeated ItemMetadata?

Tags: msbuild

In `MSBuild`, we may define Item metadata as:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <DProjs Include="$(GroupProjPath)app.dproj">
            <DCP>test1</DCP>
        </DProjs>
    </ItemGroup>
```

I may also define duplicate Item metadata:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <DProjs Include="$(GroupProjPath)app.dproj">
            <DCP>test1</DCP>
            <DCP>test2</DCP>
            <DCP>test3</DCP>
        </DProjs>
    </ItemGroup>
```

But how would I access 3 distinct item metadata value?

```
<Message Text="%(DProjs.DCP)" />
```

always return `test3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the metadata value `<DCP>test1;test2;test3</DCP>` which is what you would expect if repeated values were allowed.  You can use the `CreateItem` task to turn it into a list of items that can then be batched (looped over), or use it however you meant.